# JavaScript: Understanding execution context of callback functions

Tags: javascript, this

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('From click listener - arrow function:', this);
});
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('From click listener - normal function:', this);
});
Promise.resolve().then(function () { 
  console.log('From Promise - normal function:', this);
});
Promise.resolve().then(() => { 
  console.log('From Promise - arrow function:', this);
});
setTimeout(function () {
  console.log('From setTimeout - normal function:', this);
});
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log('From setTimeout - arrow function:', this);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button>Click me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Please have a look at the above code snippet. I'd like to understand how `this` in inferred in each of the above cases. How is `this` inside callback functions (eg., the callbacks passed to `window.setTimeout`, `Promise.then`, `HTMLElement.addEventListener`) inferred, in general.

Comment: Maybe using strict mode would help a bit to distinguish the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing an arrow function, you'll inherit the `this` from the outside. If you are writing a "normal" function, you'll create a new context of `this`.

Doesn't matter if it is a promise, `window.setTimeout` or any other thing.

For example:

```js
this.value = 2
const example = {
  value: 1,
  arrowFunction: () => this.value,
  normalFunction: function () { return this.value },
}

console.log(example.arrowFunction()) // will print 2
console.log(example.normalFunction()) // will return 1
```

You can read more about that here: https://www.quora.com/What-does-this-in-JavaScript-mean/answer/Quildreen-Motta

Comment: Could you be more elaborate? What do you mean by "creating new" and "inheriting"?

Comment: @karthikaruna I added a code example. I think that now is more elaborated.